# calculate road distance between two locations by providing latitude and longitude of source and destination .net or javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net

Hie Friends,

I searched for the same and found the formulae to find the Arial distance between two locations by latitude and longitude but I want to find the road distance between two locations in .net (C#) or javascript/jquery by providing the latitude and longitude of source and destination.

kindly help if anyone is having a solution for the same.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy arithmetic formular for the road distance because at least some knowledge in graph algorithms together with detailed map data is needed to do. Fortunately there are web services around e.g. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro which perform the calculation for you. Javascript interfaces are available and from the C# perspective it is a simple web request. Please check the usage agreements first.

Comment: your link is helpful but i am not able to generate the code as per my requirement. Could you please help in this regard.